# Entity Framework with table join to another database with Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have an EF code first application.  I have a column PersonId that I need to join with another database (warehouse) table Persons which contains all the people in our organization.

I have read that one solution is to use a view then make my entity model from the view but this seems quite painful if we have a PersonId column in many tables.

How best to return back all rows from table A joined with a table B from another database on key column PersonId, really to return PersonDisplayName from table B?

There has got to be a best practice for this situation?

Comment: How is referential integrity enforced across databases?

Comment: Table A has FK to Table B (table b is just reference information to provide more details about the person)

Comment: try to use the indexed view to make the query result faster, but why you put the table people in the database warehouse?

Comment: Let me be more specific: Since you cannot create a foreign key constraint in one table that references a table in a different database, what mechanism are you already using to maintain the integrity of the foreign keys in the child table? Are you using triggers, a batch cleanup process perhaps?

Comment: I don't have any FK's setup between the tables.  It is purely personId in one table for the application and in the warehouse we have another personId (the warehouse never removes the personId)